# How can I overcome the requests limitation using app_store_scraper on Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, app-store

I am trying to run the following code on python:

```
from app_store_scraper import AppStore
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import datetime as dt

sites = ['nike-training-club','nike-run-club','nike-snkrs-sneaker-release','nike']
paises = ['cn','us','gb','jp','fr','de','mx','es','kr','it']

df_app = pd.DataFrame()
for i in sites:
    for j in paises: 
        try:
            nike = AppStore(country= j, app_name= i)
            nike.review()
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            r.status_code = "Connection refused"
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(nike.reviews),columns=['review'])
        df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('review').tolist()))
        df2 = df2[['rating','date']]
        df2['date'] = df2['date'].dt.date
        df2['pais'] = j
        df2['site'] = i
        df_app =  df_app.append(df2)
```

It worked with smaller lists, but started showing the following error messages after a while:

```
2021-06-30 15:00:06,310 [ERROR] Base - Something went wrong: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='amp-api.apps.apple.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/catalog/us/apps/835599320/reviews?l=en-GB&offset=0&limit=20&platform=web&additionalPlatforms=appletv%2Cipad%2Ciphone%2Cmac (Caused by ResponseError('too many 429 error responses'))
2021-06-30 15:00:06,323 [INFO] Base - [id:835599320] Fetched 0 reviews (0 fetched in total)
```

I think app store stopped me after too many requests.

Answer (score 2):

you are hitting public endpoints for these websites and hitting the limit, ideally put a good gap b/w the calls (simply do time.sleep(duration) to not go to that state and also not put load into these endpoints (ethical).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you recommend the duration I should use for it?

Comment: You'll have to see what are the limits for these websites and then give a delay to meet those. For eg. if a website allows 100 requests/sec. And right now you doing 500 then you should pause after every 100. Also another minor suggestion is to swap your for loops first run on paises and then sites :)