# Improving performance when looping through country codes in App Store Scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, podcast

I am using the [App Store Scraper](https://pypi.org/project/app-store-scraper/) to get podcast reviews from the Apple Store. One thing students and I realised is that, naturally, popular international podcasts get reviews from several countries, and when we want to catch them all, we need to loop through the country codes. As even people in Sweden or Poland may comment on a BBC podcast in English, we did not want to exclude any countries but use the whole set, which I have (as a starting point) hard-coded as follows:

```
# Select country codes
# full list of countries where Apple podcasts are available has been shared on Gitlab
countries=["DZ", "AO", "AI",
"AR", "AM", "AU",
"AT", "AZ", "BH",
"BB", "BY", "BE",
"BZ", "BM", "BO",
"BW", "BR", "VG",
"BN", "BG", "CA",
"KY", "CL", "CN",
"CO", "CR", "HR",
"CY", "CZ", "DK",
"DM", "EC", "EG",
"SV", "EE", "FI",
"FR", "DE", "GH",
"GB", "GR", "GD",
"GT", "GY", "HN",
"HK", "HU", "IS",
"IN", "ID", "IE",
"IL", "IT", "JM",
"JP", "JO", "KE",
"KW", "LV", "LB",
"LT", "LU", "MO",
"MG", "MY", "ML",
"MT", "MU", "MX",
"MS", "NP", "NL",
"NZ", "NI", "NE",
"NG", "NO", "OM",
"PK", "PA", "PY",
"PE", "PH", "PL",
"PT", "QA", "MK",
"RO", "RU", "SA",
"SN", "SG", "SK",
"SI", "ZA", "KR",
"ES", "LK", "SR",
"SE", "CH", "TW",
"TZ", "TH", "TN",
"TR", "UG", "UA",
"AE", "US", "UY",
"UZ", "VE", "VN",
"YE"]
```

Then I loop through this list to get the reviews, which works OK -- but it the process is very slow! Whenever a podcast does not have any reviews, the app store scraper (according to the notifications I get) tries the request 20 times before moving on to the next item, so the loop takes ages. How can I make the process faster, e.g. forcing the script to move on if the first request is unsuccessful? This is what I have so far:

```
# Set podcast details
app_id = 1614435903
app_name = '28ish-days-later'
# important: country codes will be selected from the list above

# Set output path
path_out = "podcast_reviews"

filename_csv = f'{app_name}_reviews_table.csv'
file_csv = directory + path_out + filename_csv

# Optional: use (how_many=n) after sys.review to limit output
# otherwise all reviews are fetched

for c in countries:
    # Create class object
    sysk = Podcast(country=c, app_name=app_name, app_id=app_id)
    sysk.review()
    print(f"No. of reviews found for country {c}:")
    #pprint(sysk.reviews)
    pprint(sysk.reviews_count)

    # NOTE: the review count seen on the landing page differs from the actual number of reviews fetched.
    # This is simply because only some users who rated the app also leave reviews.
```

The notification I get in the output when no reviews are found is this:

```
ERROR:Base:Something went wrong: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='amp-api.podcasts.apple.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/catalog/dz/podcasts/1614435903/reviews?l=en-GB&offset=0&limit=20 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 404 error responses'))

No. of reviews found for country DZ:
0
```

My first attempt was to include a `try` and `except`, but that does not stop the script from attempting the max retries before raising the error, so I got rid of it. Perhaps it is possible to give the script a "how_many=1" limitation for all country codes and write only the ones that retrieve a result to a new list before starting the loop. I will post this as an answer if it works.

Comment: _the app store scraper (according to the notifications I get) tries the request 20 times before moving on to the next item_ I don't think that's correct statement. What "notifications" do you refer to? According to docs _The maximum number of reviews fetched per request is 20. To minimise the number of calls, the limit of 20 is hardcoded. This means the review() method will always grab more than the how_many argument supplied with an increment of 20._

Comment: Anyway, have a look at settings for retries here: https://github.com/cowboy-bebug/app-store-scraper/blob/9a50bdc112888dfea6ebb9c19694872899794de3/app_store_scraper/base.py#L117

Comment: I am aware that I will always get at least 20 podcast reviews per call, but I am still hoping there is a way to stop it from calling more than once if no reviews are found. My error is currently "Caused by ResponseError('too many 404 error responses')" and the performance is unreasonably slow.

Comment: It makes max of 3 retries with backoff factor of 3 (that increase the time between retries). You can remove the 404 status from status_forcelist (see the link to source code in my previous comment). And here is the link to Retries docs in urlib3 package (https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.Retry)

Comment: i.e. I don't see way to overcome that, other than changing the source code of the scraper (i.e. no nice way to set these via your code)

Comment: I also found a related issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199938/how-can-i-overcome-the-requests-limitation-using-app-store-scraper-on-python

Comment: Note that you have status code 404 (too many 404 error responses), while they have 429 (too many requests). i.e. they really may have exceeded the API limits. It looks like in your case it just retries 3 times (4 requests in total) and then moves on (I still don't understand why you say it tries 20 times). Both 404 and 429 status code are on status_forcelist

Comment: Other option is just to set total to `0`, i.e. no retries

Comment: The better solution may then be to check the existence of review first via ```requests``` or so and not use the app store scraper for that step at all.

Comment: Yes, that's also an alternative approach

Comment: Just to clarifiy, if you decide to edit the source code of the scraper,  it is better to edit the call of `_get` in `Base.review()` here (https://github.com/cowboy-bebug/app-store-scraper/blob/9a50bdc112888dfea6ebb9c19694872899794de3/app_store_scraper/base.py#L186) and pass respective arguments, instead of changing `_get()`

Comment: No, messing with the source code isn't my cup of tea. I wrote some code to access the URLs with ```requests``` and check if the HTML has ```"@type":"review"```. If so, the country code is added to a new list to feed into the app scraper. I will post the code as an answer below. This one is swift!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion with @buran above, here is my solution for checking the existence of reviews via `requests` first before feeding a much shorter country code list into the `app store scraper`:

```
## check if countries have reviews at all
import requests

# URL for the podcasts
url = "https://podcasts.apple.com/{}/podcast/28ish-days-later/id1614435903?see-all=reviews"

# create a list to store countries with reviews
countries_reviewed = []

# iterate over the list of country codes
for country_code in countries:
    # format the URL with the current country code
    url_new = url.format(country_code)

    # send HTTP GET request
    response = requests.get(url_new)

    # check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # check if the specified review string is present in HTML
        if '"@type":"Review"' in response.text:
            # if present, add the country code to the list
            countries_reviewed.append(country_code)
            print(f"The podcast has reviews for country code '{country_code}'.")
        else:
            print(f"No reviews found for country code '{country_code}'.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve the content for country code '{country_code}'. Status code: {response.status_code}")

# Print the final list of countries with reviews
print("Countries with reviews:", countries_reviewed)
```

This gives me the following output in a short amount of time:

```
No reviews found for country code 'LV'.
No reviews found for country code 'LB'.
No reviews found for country code 'LT'.
No reviews found for country code 'LU'.
No reviews found for country code 'MO'.
No reviews found for country code 'MG'.
No reviews found for country code 'MY'.
No reviews found for country code 'ML'.
No reviews found for country code 'MT'.
No reviews found for country code 'MU'.
No reviews found for country code 'MX'.
No reviews found for country code 'MS'.
No reviews found for country code 'NP'.
The podcast has reviews for country code 'NL'.
No reviews found for country code 'NZ'.
No reviews found for country code 'NI'.
No reviews found for country code 'NE'.
No reviews found for country code 'NG'.
No reviews found for country code 'NO'.
No reviews found for country code 'OM'.
No reviews found for country code 'PK'.
No reviews found for country code 'PA'.
No reviews found for country code 'PY'.
No reviews found for country code 'PE'.
No reviews found for country code 'PH'.
No reviews found for country code 'PL'.
No reviews found for country code 'PT'.
No reviews found for country code 'QA'.
No reviews found for country code 'MK'.
No reviews found for country code 'RO'.
No reviews found for country code 'RU'.
No reviews found for country code 'SA'.
No reviews found for country code 'SN'.
No reviews found for country code 'SG'.
No reviews found for country code 'SK'.
No reviews found for country code 'SI'.
No reviews found for country code 'ZA'.
No reviews found for country code 'KR'.
No reviews found for country code 'ES'.
No reviews found for country code 'LK'.
No reviews found for country code 'SR'.
The podcast has reviews for country code 'SE'.
The podcast has reviews for country code 'CH'.
No reviews found for country code 'TW'.
No reviews found for country code 'TZ'.
No reviews found for country code 'TH'.
No reviews found for country code 'TN'.
No reviews found for country code 'TR'.
No reviews found for country code 'UG'.
No reviews found for country code 'UA'.
No reviews found for country code 'AE'.
The podcast has reviews for country code 'US'.
No reviews found for country code 'UY'.
No reviews found for country code 'UZ'.
No reviews found for country code 'VE'.
No reviews found for country code 'VN'.
No reviews found for country code 'YE'.
Countries with reviews: ['AU', 'CA', 'DK', 'GB', 'NL', 'SE', 'CH', 'US']
```